# Rotational equilibrium for an object

Tags: torque

[image]

I have two silly queries:

1. In case $1$,a rod $AB$ is attached to a string at point $C$. Here the weight is acting at the center of mass $O$. My question is: * Is it even possible to keep a rod hanging like this*? If it were possible,then the rod is in rotational equilibrium,but as we can see the line of action of the weight is not going through $C$. So,there should be net torque with respect to $C$. In light of this logic,how can a rod keep hanging in this position?
2. In case $2$,we imagine a *cylinder* whose cross sectional area is large enough *standing on ground*. Now we all know the center of mass $O$ is at the center of the cylinder. As the body is in rotational equilibrium, the net torque with respect to *any point* should be $0$. But here, the line of action of weight that is acting at $O$ does not pass through $D$. So,there should be a net torque about $D$. But,still we don't see the cylinder falling down with respect to $D$ even if there is a net torque. Why does this happen?

I will be grateful for clearing my doubts.

Comment: If you have drawn the only force on the cylinder, then it must be accelerating downward.  If it is at rest, then there must be other forces on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a net torque about the fixed point C from gravity, so the body will rotate (and oscillate) until ultimately it hangs without moving vertically where gravity provides no torque.
2. There is a force of constraint on the object from the ground in addition to the force of gravity; the sum of the forces provides translational and rotational equilibrium.